# How Do You Get the bufspec While Using Vimdiff Through Git

Tags: git, vim, git-merge, vimdiff

I've read [Vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) and [Viewing differences with Vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_08.html#08.7) plus doing various google searches using things like "vimdiff multiple", "vimdiff git", "vimdiff commands" etc.

When using do or diffg I get the error "More than two buffers in diff mode, don't know which one to use".

When using diffg v:fname_in I get "No matching buffer for v:fname_in".

From the vimdiff documentation:

> :[range]diffg[et] [bufspec]
>    Modify the current buffer to undo difference with another
>    buffer.  If [bufspec] is given, that buffer is used.  If
>    [bufspec] refers to the current buffer then nothing happens.
>    Otherwise this only works if there is one other buffer in diff
>    mode.

and more:

> When 'diffexpr' is not empty, Vim evaluates to obtain a diff file in the
>    format mentioned.  These variables are set to the file names used:
>
> v:fname_in     original file
>    v:fname_new        new version of the same file
>    v:fname_out        resulting diff file

So, I need to get the name of bufspec, but the default variables (fname_in, fname_new, and fname_out) aren't set.

I ran the command git mergetool on a linux box through a terminal.

[Edit]
A partial solution that bred more questions.  I used the "filename" at the bottom of the buffer.  It's only a half answer, because occasionally I get a file does not exist error.  I believe it's consistently the remote version of the file that "does not exist".  I suspect this has something to do with git and indexing.

**How do you get the bufspec value *consistently* while using vimdiff through git-mergetool?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `[bufspec]` argument above can be a buffer number, a pattern for a buffer name or a part of a buffer name.  Examples:

- `:diffget`  Use the other buffer which is in diff mode
- `:diffget 3`  Use buffer 3
- `:diffget v2`  Use the buffer which matches `v2` and is in
  diff mode (e.g., `file.c.v2`)

I always use the number of the buffer.

Comment: So use :diffget and whatever is the character combo after the second dot?

Comment: That's awesome.  You'd think that would've been easy to guess.  Guess I was getting too irritated to see something so simple.  *sigh*  Thank you Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Type in   "2" , and then ctrl-g  , it shows you the buffer number, and the file.

Answer (score 3):

To list the available buffer numbers and names (valid values for *bufspec*), use `:ls`

(From the title of this question, that's what I thought was being asked, and was why I looked here.)

`:ls` will list the buffer numbers and names. The window currently containing the cursor will be denoted by a `%`:

```
:ls
  1 #a   "Gemfile.lock"                 line 1
  2 %a   "Gemfile.lock.LOCAL.4828.lock" line 1
  3  a   "Gemfile.lock.BASE.4828.lock"  line 0
  4  a   "Gemfile.lock.REMOTE.4828.lock" line 0
```

When using `diffget` or `diffput`, any substring that uniquely matches a buffer name can be used as the *bufspec* argument. For example, assuming the state reflected in the above snippet, we can use:

`diffget REM`

to grab `Gemfile.lock.REMOTE.4828.lock`'s  version of the change that is currently under the cursor.